# jQuery filter selection options based on element classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

have a bit of a confusing question today.

I am trying to hide options within a select element based on the classes that are contained in a certain element.

I will first explain my setup:

I have two select elements

```
<select class="form-control select-box">
                 <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
                 <?php while($make = $makeFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                 {
                 echo '
                 <option value="'.$make["Make"].'">'.$make["Make"].'</option>
                 ';
                 } ?>
</select>
<select class="form-control last-select select-box">
                 <option value="model-any">Model (Any)</option>
                 <?php while($model = $modelFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                 {
                 echo '
                 <option value="'.$model["Model"].'">'.$model["Model"].'</option>
                 ';
                 } ?>
</select>
```

These two elements are using a PHP while loop to loop through the 'Make' and 'Model' column of my SQL table.

I then have this block of code that lists all of the results to the front end:

```
<?php include('db-affinity/filter.php'); ?>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
      <?php while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
      echo '
      <div class="makes ' . $row["Make"] . '">
        <div class="listing-container">
          <a href="carpage.php"><h3 class="model-listing-title clearfix">'.$row["Make"].' '.$row["Model"].' '.$row["Variant"].'</h3></a>
          <h3 class="price-listing">£'.number_format($row['Price']).'</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="listing-container-spec">
         <img src="'.(explode(',', $row["PictureRefs"])[0]).'" class="stock-img-finder"/>
          <div class="ul-listing-container">
            <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul">
              <li class="diesel-svg list-svg">'.$row["FuelType"].'</li>
              <li class="saloon-svg list-svg">'.$row["Bodytype"].'</li>
              <li class="gear-svg list-svg">'.$row["Transmission"].'</li>
              <li class="color-svg list-svg">'.$row["Colour"].'</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul other-specs-ul h4-style">
            <li>Mileage: '.number_format($row["Mileage"]).'</li>
            <li>Engine size: '.$row["EngineSize"].'cc</li>
          </ul>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style checked-btn hover-listing-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> History checked 
          </button>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style more-details-btn hover-listing-btn tst-mre-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> More details 
          </button>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style test-drive-btn hover-listing-btn tst-mre-btn"><span class="test-drive-glyph"></span> Test drive 
          </button>
          <h4 class="h4-style listing-photos-count"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> 5 More photos</h4>
        </div>
        </div>
          ';
      } ?>
```

As you can see this block is looped as well to display all of the rows of my SQL table.

I then have this jQuery to hide all classes that don't have the same value as the option that has been selected in the first select element:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.form-control').change(function(){
    var make = $(this).val();
    if(make != 'make-any'){
      $('.makes').hide();
      $('.'+make).show();
      } else {
        $('.makes').show();
        }
    });
  });</script>
```

As you can see it hides the div in the listing that contains the class "makes" thus filtering all of the makes.

When a user selects an option such as BMW I want the 'Models' select options to only show the 'Models' that are associated with BMW so for example I could add another class to the makes div that includes the 'Model' just like this:

```
<div class="makes ' . $row["Make"] . ' ' . $row["Model"] . '">
```

So I'd like jQuery to hide the options in my 'Models' select element based on what 'Make' has been selected, I only want to 'Models' associated with the 'Make' of the div above.

Any examples of how I could do this?

Comment: FYI, You can't hide options cross-browser.

Comment: @adeneo Sure you can. Just detach them and store them, ready to be re-inserted if the "make" selection is updated.

Comment: Can I use disable instead?

Comment: @KyleNeedham - That would be *removing* the elements, which of course is not a problem, the issue is with *hiding* the options, hence the comment.